# Remove outliers from a set of 3d points before clustering Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a set of 3d points in Matlab but the problem is that my data found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/78z5n52yc3e17bm/XX2.mat). And as you can see there are some outliers which are affecting my clustering results. So if anyone could please advise how I can delete these outliers from my data.

Comment: Downloaded the data and now watching and wondering if that's a zombie or something? :)

Comment: :) this is a 3d data of me holding two boxes. I hope if anyone can assist me on removing these outliers

Comment: haha! Oh damn, sorry about the comment ;)

Comment: don't sorry, its okay :)

Comment: Just an idea - Do they have `imdilate` for 3D data? If so, maybe do some of that and select the biggest 3D connected blob to be you?

Comment: I've checked Matlab, I have it, but it only takes grayscale, binary, or packed binary image.

Comment: Guess you need to call up Boston! :D

Comment: Have you considered using density-based clustering, which is supposedly much more robust to outliers? (It will return them as "noise"). I don't think k-means results will be convincing, even after you have removed the outliers.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Thanks for your comment.  I've tried but I'm keen on using K-means, so you mean it is not possible to remove outliers if I'm using the Kmeans?

Comment: No. Even *after* removing outliers, k-means will likely not work well. Just increase k to 5, and you will likely have one cluster that is all-outliers; and the remaining outliers don't have that much effect on the result anymore... yet, it is all but convincing in my opinion.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I've tried using the Dbscan code found in this link to cluster the data in my question but its not working on my data https://code.google.com/p/dmfa07/downloads/detail?name=DBSCAN.M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at your data, I don't think any clustering algorithm will do what you want. Instead, you will probably need to train a classifier. This is what the Kinect people did, train a classifier using millions of real and synthetic postures, to have it label limbs, head, etc.

The reason why I don't think density based clustering will work either is because your data is a single, density-connected, body-with-two-boxes-shaped blob. But without knowing what a "body" and a "box" is, segmentation will be rather arbitrary. Or in the case of density based clustering: it will not segment at all, or it will segment e.g. by the rather low resultion of your z axis. Furthermore, your X and Y axes come from a grid based image scan (I assume), so you have a very uniform density on the X and Y axes - but the arms, for example, are not of a lower density than the body or boxes.

You can, however, use DBSCAN with rather broad (and easy to set) parameters to remove the noise.

E.g. in [ELKI](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/) the following parameters yield reasonable results:

```
java -jar elki.jar -dbc.in /tmp/XX.csv -algorithm clustering.DBSCAN \
-dbscan.epsilon 0.05 -dbscan.minpts 100
```

The majority cluster is your data with the outliers removed; even with this blob near the foot removed.

To speed up the clustering process, you can add the parameters

```
-db.index tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeFactory \
-pagefile.pagesize 1000 -spatial.bulkstrategy SortTileRecursiveBulkSplit
```

which yields a runtime opf 4.5 seconds here. This obviously is not good enough for realtime operation as on a Kinect; but it is not surprising to see a *directed* classification algorithm to outperform an unsupervised method - this is in fact to be expected.

Here is the result of clustering the data set with the parameters above:

[image: DBSCAN result]